# How can my wife watch her photos on our Apple TV?

Tags: icloud, appletv, photo-stream

My wife would like to watch her photos on our Apple TV. She is logged in on our Apple TV and we are also sharing an iCloud subscription as well.

Is there a way to do that? Or somehow load her photos to my photo library?

Comment: Easy way for anyone to view photos on Apple TV is to simply use airplay. As a quick solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly enough, this not possible in the way you’d expect. The UI and settings of the Apple TV suggest you can simply switch between registered users and by switching, you’d gain access to that user’s content. Unfortunately, that’s not the case. Seriously, the person who designed this ought to be escorted to a remote place, far far away… (no, not that far, even further!)

The simplest way to watch photo’s taken by a different user is to cast them from the user’s iPad or iPhone to the Apple TV (via AirPlay). Alternatively, you could create a shared album and the other user needs to move/copy all their photos to this shared album. But that too is not an easy task; functionality for managing your photo’s is extremely lacking. All this is completely beyond my understanding. Why, Apple? Why?

Kind regards from a long time, but ever so frustrated Apple user!